# How to convert this Influx querie into Homeassistant sensor value?

Tags: automation, yaml, influxdb

I need help converting an InfluxDB query into YAML format that can be read by Homeassistant.

The Influx database is hosted on an external server and is also seamlessly integrated into dashboards by Grafana as follows:

```
SELECT mean("temperature_C") FROM "LaCrosse-TX141THBv2" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```

----------
This value should now also be used by Homeassistant as a input sensor value. I have created the following YAML:

```
sensor:
  - platform: influxdb
    host: network-pi
    username: config
    port: 8086
    password: !secret influx_password
    queries:
      - name: badtemperatur 
        group_function: last
        where: '"name" = ''LaCrosse-TX141THBv2'''
        #measurement: '"LaCrosse-TX141THBv2"'
        field: temperature_C
        database: monitoring
```

----------
However, I get this error message under "Developer Tools/Check configuration" in Homeassistant:

```
Invalid config for [sensor.influxdb]: required key not provided @ data['queries'][0]['measurement']. Got None. (See ?, line ?).
```

In the Hass documentation there is the a template for an Influx value as a sensor:

```
sensor:
  - platform: influxdb
    host: localhost
    username: home-assistant
    password: password
    queries:
      - name: last value of foo
        unit_of_measurement: °C
        value_template: '{{ value | round(1) }}'
        group_function: last
        where: '"name" = ''foo'''
        measurement: '"°C"'
        field: value
        database: db1
      - name: Min for last hour
        unit_of_measurement: "%"
        value_template: '{{ value | round(1) }}'
        group_function: min
        where: '"entity_id" = ''salon'' and time > now() - 1h'
        measurement: '"%"'
        field: tmp
        database: db2
```

However, it is a mystery to me what the following line would be in my, case:
This can't refer to the time, can it?

Many thanks to everyone who could help me!